# How to increase width of search bar in header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have to increase the width of search bar and make the border invisible while keeping it mobile responsive. Something like:

```
http://oneclass.com/#!/notes
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">dss</a>
</div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control ipt" placeholder="Search" name="q">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </li>
            <li>
                 <a  href="study_material.php">Study Material</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                 <a  href="about.php">About us</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                 <a  href="">Blog</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS ... 
Just add some style to the class element you want to edit...

I guess you can use something like this:

```
.ipt {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 45px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/lokezimowo/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 0):

you can add some CSS to the input "text" tag.(which with a ipt class here).

```
.ipt {
   border:none;   //make the border invisible
   width:75%;     //set width to % instead of pixel to make it responsible.
   height:50px;
   font-size:22px; //control the text area's height of the text-input tag.
}
```

you may check a simple demo here. http://codepen.io/fukurouzhong/pen/JKdLVd